How to bake a Swedish Christmas bread?
Around Christmas in Sweden, it's common to see vörtbröd for sale. This spiced Christmas bread is traditionally made using wort, a by-product of beer.
What are some alternatives / replacements for wort in the baking of vörtbröd?

The recipes I’ve seen don’t involve wort. Do you have a particular recipe you’re trying to adapt?

Wort is not "a by-product" of beer. Wort is what beer is made from, so if you use wort for other things, you make less beer. Spent grains, on the other hand, are a by-product after wort is made from them (chickens love them.)

Wort is extracted from malted barley, so barley malt extract (dry keeps better than liquid) would be a direct replacement (with dilution in water to get it to the specific gravity of typical wort).
It is not clear from the link if the wort has been hopped before use in bread; liquid malts are commonly available pre-hopped or not, while dry malt usually is not. If you need it hopped and are starting with unhopped extract you'd have to boil hops in it, at which point you'd be making an extract-based wort, not substituting anything for it (unless you consider extract based wort a "substitute" for mashing grain malts and extracting them yourself, as some beer enthusiasts do.)
You could probably substitute other sugar solutions (molasses, honey, golden syrup) appropriately diluted; but they won't behave exactly the same as malt sugar in bread does.
If unfermented "malt soda" is available to you in your local markets, that might be the closest thing to an off-the-shelf substitute for wort. However, if it's got a bunch of preservatives in it, those might interfere with your yeast.

Scandi beer/wort used for this sort of thing is very lightly hopped. Diluted malt syrup is a good substitute.
